# How costly is it to call sendMessage() from the background script to content script once per second?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying to work on a Chrome extension that involves a timer countdown from five minutes when the user changes the URL: I'm thinking of counting down from the background script because the timer I coded in the content script doesn't persist counting down unless the (popup) chrome extension is manually opened by clicking its icon on the upper right of the browser window.

The thing is, I also want to change the html text of my popup to show the countdown progress when the user clicks and opens my extension, and this can only be done on the content script because background scripts can't access the DOM (as far as I know). I'm thinking of passing the countdown progress from my background script to my content script at every second, where it gets stored/updated in a variable in the content script, that can then be used to change my popup text. Is this really resource heavy?

Any other workarounds would be cool too (I'm new to web development lol).

my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Drill Sergeant",
  "description": "Tracks time spent on 'watchlist' websites",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
  "web_accessible_resources": ["background.js"],
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "webNavigation", "notifications", "tabs"]
}
```

my non-working timer in content script:

```
function countDown(){
  var a = 300;
  setInterval(function(){
    a--;

    if(a == 0)
    {
      alert("!!!");
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

how I included my content script in my .html file ("..." just means that there's irrelevant html code above my script tag):

```
   <body>
     ...
    <script src = contentscript.js></script>
   </body>
```

Comment: Any performance-related concerns must be answered by measuring e.g. by running a performance profiler in devtools both in the background page and in the web page. Unless your object is really huge (many megabytes) and/or has lots of nested children, the overhead is absolutely negligible.

Comment: Awesome, I'm only planning on passing a number so that should be fine.